# What is the difference between the WordPress **_e()** and **__()** functions? How they exactly works?

Tags: php, content-management-system, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am pretty new in WordPress theme development and I have the following doubt.

I am developing a custom theme that use **BootStrap** CSS framework in the usual way: I have create the set of file: **index.php**, **header.php**, **footer.php**, etcetc

For the comments, at the beginning, I have create an empty, **comments.php** file and (obviously) doing in this way I could neither read nor post new comments.

So I have copy and paste the content of the **comments.php** file present in the WP **Twenty_Fourteen** theme.

So it seems to work correctly but now I have some doubts.

This is the code of the **comments.php** file that I am using at this time:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying Comments
 *
 * The area of the page that contains comments and the comment form.

 */

/*
 * If the current post is protected by a password and the visitor has not yet
 * entered the password we will return early without loading the comments.
 */
if ( post_password_required() ) {
    return;
}
?>

<div id="comments" class="comments-area">

    <?php if ( have_comments() ) : ?>

    <h2 class="comments-title">
        <?php
            printf( _n( 'One thought on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', '%1$s thoughts on &ldquo;%2$s&rdquo;', get_comments_number(), 'twentyfourteen' ),
                number_format_i18n( get_comments_number() ), get_the_title() );
        ?>
    </h2>

    <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : ?>
    <nav id="comment-nav-above" class="navigation comment-navigation" role="navigation">
        <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Comment navigation', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></h1>
        <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '&larr; Older Comments', 'twentyfourteen' ) ); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments &rarr;', 'twentyfourteen' ) ); ?></div>
    </nav><!-- #comment-nav-above -->
    <?php endif; // Check for comment navigation. ?>

    <ol class="comment-list">
        <?php
            wp_list_comments( array(
                'style'      => 'ol',
                'short_ping' => true,
                'avatar_size'=> 34,
            ) );
        ?>
    </ol><!-- .comment-list -->

    <?php if ( get_comment_pages_count() > 1 && get_option( 'page_comments' ) ) : ?>
    <nav id="comment-nav-below" class="navigation comment-navigation" role="navigation">
        <h1 class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Comment navigation', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></h1>
        <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_comments_link( __( '&larr; Older Comments', 'twentyfourteen' ) ); ?></div>
        <div class="nav-next"><?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments &rarr;', 'twentyfourteen' ) ); ?></div>
    </nav><!-- #comment-nav-below -->
    <?php endif; // Check for comment navigation. ?>

    <?php if ( ! comments_open() ) : ?>
    <p class="no-comments"><?php _e( 'Comments are closed.', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif; // have_comments() ?>

    <?php comment_form(); ?>

</div><!-- #comments -->
```

As you can see in the previous code appear something like:

```
<?php _e( 'Comments are closed.', 'twentyfourteen' ); ?>
```

I know that **_e** function displays the returned translated text from translate() (but in what languanges?)

I also find something like:

```
<?php next_comments_link( __( 'Newer Comments &rarr;', 'twentyfourteen' ) ); ?>
```

Looking at WordPress documentation it seems to understand that the meaning of __ is similar to the _e function (or am I saying wrong things?)

The thing that I can't understand is how it work the **e** function (and the *__ function)*.

Reading the documentation it say that the usage is:

```
 <?php _e( $text, $domain ) ?>
```

where:

> **$text**: is a string that represent the **text to translate**
>
> **$domain**: is a string) that represent the **domain to retrieve the translated text** (so I think that it represent where the translation
>   could be found)

Ok, so in the previous code I have that

**$text** is: 'Newer Comments →'

and that:

**$domain** is: **twentyfourteen** that is the name or directory name (or what else?) of the preinstalled WordPress TwentyFourteen theme

So my doubts are:

1) My **'$text'** is **'Newer Comments →'**, so where is the translation? and in what languanges are definied?

2) What is the difference between ***e()*** and **_()** functions?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: 1) All localizations of theme are stored in theme_dir/languages/*.mo. http://codex.wordpress.org/Translating_WordPress#gettext_files
2) _e() just echo __()

Answer (score 3):

`_e()` is used to output a translated string whereas `__()` returns the translated text.

So `_e()` is basically a short version of `echo __()`.

If no translation exists then the string ($text) is returned. Otherwise the translated string is returned. Language files need to be added for translations to work.

Look in the languages folder of twentyfourteen.

Comment: Ok, so let me see if I well understand how it work: I have a file that contains the translation in a set of languages (example: Englis, Italian and French). So if I use the __e() function and my broweser is setted for the English language it return to me the definied string in English, if the browser is setted in Italian it return and print the string in Italian language (taking the value from the translation file). Is it right? But what is the defference between output the translated string with _e() and return the translated thex using __(). Is not the same operation?